# AutoMapper taking 4 seconds to map 19 objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper

I've been stuck on this for a while, I am stumped. Automapper is taking 4 seconds to map 19 objects. The operation should take milliseconds or nanoseconds on my machine (24gb ram, 3.6Ghz i7).

This is the mapping call.

```
 var messageDtos = AutoMapperConfig.Mapper.Map<List<Message>, List<MessageDTO>>(messages);
```

This is my Automapper config

```
    public static class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static IMapper Mapper;
    public static void Configure()
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<UserDTO, User>();
            cfg.CreateMap<ConversationUser, ConversationUserDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<ConversationUserDTO, ConversationUser>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Conversation, ConversationDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<ConversationDTO, Conversation>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ConversationUsers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ConversationUsers));

            cfg.CreateMap<Message, MessageDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<MessageDTO, Message>();

        });

        Mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    }
}
```

Here are the relevant objects. They aren't anything crazy.

```
public class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MediaMessage> MediaMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ReadReceipt> ReadReceipts { get; set; }

    public Message()
    {
        CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class MessageDTO
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public virtual ConversationDTO Conversation { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDTO User { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MediaMessage> MediaMessages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ReadReceipt> ReadReceipts { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string TransferGuid { get; set; }
}

public class ConversationDTO
{
    public int ConversationId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserDTO Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConversationUserDTO> ConversationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual Message RecentMessage { get; set; }
}

public class UserDTO
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string TwitterHandel { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a screenshot in dot trace showing how long Automapper is taking, not sure how much insight it provides, I just installed dotrace yesterday to figure this out.
[image: Automapper dotTrace breakdown]

Comment: I think this line is causing problem .ForMember(dest => dest.ConversationUsers, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ConversationUsers));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, database calls are being made.

AutoMapper is calling your relational property getters, which are using EntityFramework to load the data from the database.

The quick fix is to disable lazy-loaded collections.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Message` class is part of your Entity Framework model, and you seem to have lazy loading enabled. So while mapping from that `Message` class, the properties `MediaMessages` and `ReadReceipts` are not loaded from the database yet and AutoMapper triggers them to be lazily loaded. So those 4 seconds are actually 2 database calls happening during the mapping.

You should eagerly load entities before mapping them. Probably a better idea to disable lazy loading and manually `.Include()` them during your query.